# Subscribtion to service observable emits even after component destruction

Tags: angular, service, observable, provider

I'm having trouble with an observable in my service. The following code illustrates this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  public globalVariable: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
}
```

I have a feature component:

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
   constructor(public myService : MyService ) {
      this.myService.globalVariable.next('newValue');
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.myService.globalVariable.subscribe(_ => console.log('=> hello'));
   }
}
```

The App Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ComponentAModule,
    ComponentBModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And lastly the project structure:

```
app-module.ts
app-routing.module.ts
-components
-- componentA
--- componentA.module.ts
--- componentA-routing.module.ts
--- componentA.component.ts
--- componentA.component.html
-- componentB
--- componentB.module.ts
--- componentB-routing.module.ts
--- componentB.component.ts
--- componentB.component.html
```

Now the issue im facing is that when i navigate to `componentA`, the output is:

```
=> hello
=> hello
```

Up untill now everything is normal and behaves as I expected. The first subscribe is triggered and then the change in `globalVariable` by `componentA`'s constructor.

However, when I navigate to `componentB` and navigate back to `componentA`, the output is:

```
=> hello
=> hello
=> hello
```

It adds one everytime i navigate back to `componentA`. As if it creates a new instance of `MyService`? Or doesn't destroy the subscribe when leaving ?

**Info:** There is no lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscription have to be manually destroyed if they aren't handled by Angular themself. This basically applies to all httpClient subscriptions you have. If you e.g. use the `| async` pipe, Angular takes care of unsubscribing.

Call `yourSubscription.unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` of your component.

What I usually do is to create a `BaseComponent` which does the unsubscribing for me. Use the below class in all your components by extending it. Wrap each subscription call in `super.addSubscription()`

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * This class handles the subscribing and unsubscribing of subscriptions to avoid memory leaks
 * and can be inherited by members
 *
 * @export
 */
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {

private subscriptions: Subscription[] = new Array<Subscription>();

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.removeSubscriptions();
}

/**
 * Adds a subscriptions so it can be deleted in ngOnDestroy
 *
 * @param subscription The subscription that should be added
 * @memberof BaseComponent
 */
protected addSubscription(subscription: Subscription) {
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
}

/**
 * Unsubscribes from any open subscriptions in the subscriptions array in ngOnDestroy
 *
 * @memberof AbstractBaseComponent
 */
private removeSubscriptions() {
    for (let subscription of this.subscriptions) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Do the following for your `ngOnInit()`, assuming you use the base class provided above:

```
export class ComponentA extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public myService : MyService ) {
       this.myService.globalVariable.next('newValue');
    }
    ngOnInit() {
       super.addSubscription(
           this.myService.globalVariable.subscribe(_ => console.log('=> hello'))
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what i was thinking but then i wondered how is it that i don't have to do this for the httpClient calls. ex: this.myService.getDataX().subscribe(_ => doSomething()); ?

Comment: I understand the way your approch works but that doesn't explain why we never unsubscribe from the httpClient calls like in the angular tutorials: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Because it is just not part of the learning process and might confuse learners with lifecycles and leaks! Nevertheless, is my answer working for you? Also, the tutorial sometimes uses the `async` pipe and as mentioned in my answer, Angular handles the unsubscribing automatically if you use the `async` pipe.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you very much. so last question. do i unsubscribe the httpClient calls as well? (I know now that i have to do it for the Observable attributes in the service)

Comment: No, don't do it in the service, but do it in the component that uses the service! There is one rule: If you type `.subscribe()` **always** wrap it with `super.addSubscription()` (as mentioned in my answer)

Comment: i know i have to do it in the component, i just wanted to know if the unsubscribing also applied to the service data fetching calls. ex: super.addSubscription(this.myService.getData().subscribe(_ => something()))

Answer (score 1):

You need to `unsubscribe` inside of `ngOnDestroy`:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

globalVariable$: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.globalVariable$ = this.myService.globalVariable.subscribe(_ => console.log('=> hello'));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.globalVariable$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: thats what i was thinking but then i wondered how is it that i don't have to do this for the httpClient calls. ex: this.myService.getDataX().subscribe(_ => doSomething()); ?

Comment: @lolplayer101 if you're subscribing like this in component or service `this.myService.getDataX().subscribe(_ => doSomething()); , you need to unsubscribe using `ngOnDestroy` life hook. It's bad practice to leave subscription after destroying. If you're using only async pipe in template for subscription, it unsubscribe automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use subscribe and not async pipe, you can use the RxJs operator takeWhile.  Please see code below...

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  name = 'Angular';
  isActive: boolean;
  // returned from service.  Does not need to initialized here
  thingToSubscribeTo:Observable<any> = new Observable<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isActive = true;
    // you can replace with call to service then pipe it.
    this.thingToSubscribeTo.pipe(
      map(res => {
        // handle subscription
      }),
      takeWhile(() => this.isActive)
    );

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.isActive = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically, `takeUntil` is not the same thing as `unsubscribe`, because `unsubscribe` destroys the subscription, while `takeUntil` completes it: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil

Comment: Thanks Julien, that is helpful information.  I believe the takeUntil solution should also resolve this issue though.  However, the accepted solution may be better as it does not require implementing takeUntil on every component that has subscriptions that need to be unsubscribed to.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry if my comment came out wrong. Your approach is totally valid. I just wanted to note, that it is technically not the same to inform future readers about the difference.